# Change a parent variable in subclass, then use new value in parent class?

Tags: python

I'm just getting to grips with python, and am currently trying to change the value of a Parent class variable using a subclass method. A basic example of my code is below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request as req

class Parent(object):
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    print(url)

    def random_method(self):
        print(Parent.soup.find_all())

class Child(Parent):
    def set_url(self):
        new_url = input("Please enter a URL: ")
        request = req.Request(new_url)
        response = req.urlopen(request)
        Parent.url = new_url

    def print_url(self):
        print(Parent.url)
```

If I run the methods, the outputs are as follows.

```
run = Child()

run.Parent()
>>> www.google.com

run.set_url()
>>> Please enter a url: www.thisismynewurl.com

run.print_url()
>>> www.thisismynewurl.com

run.random_method()
>>> #Prints output for www.google.com
```

Can anyone explain why I can get the new url printing when I run print_url, but if I try and use it in another method, it reverts to the old value?

Comment: I would for sure go look over the Classes docs on python. I think you might be missing some key points on inhertiance, methods, and attributes. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Parent(object):
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    print(url)
```

The code to assign the `soup` is run once, at time of class *definition*.

Therefore no changes to `Parent.url` will be reflected in calls to the `random_method`, because the soup is already collected.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a way of rerunning with the new url then? Or will I have to rebuild my code to get the url first? I'm setting my url through a cmd input in my actual code, but since the cmd.py inherits from my Main.py, I can't get things to run correctly without my url variable having a valid URL in my Main.py.

Comment: Change your code so that the request is made by a method, not done at class level.  Then you will have to call that method explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! I was making things a lot more complicated than they needed to be, I have things working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `Parent.url` it uses the static value set inside the class Parent, not the value from the instance of the class.

Comment: So how can I print (Parent.url) from the class Child and get the new value I set? And is there a way then to use the value I set in Child in the class Parent?

Comment: @iguanabanana Why would you want to access value of a parent instance in its child? Just access the same value in the instance of a child. Since it is child, it is there